# how to deploy keras pretrained model on android

Tags: python, android, tensor, tensorflow-lite

I am working on a project in which I have trained a neural network using keras and now my next goal is to use this model on android, I Have tried so many references available on Internet but nothing works for me.

here I am attaching image of my model python code and what err I have received [this is the error I received on android while deploying the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzcDR.png)

[this is code for neural network, which I have to deploy on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHit0.png)

neural network have 3 input of float type and output is also float type.
I tried Multiple inputs and outputs method of tflite but it is showing this error.

Error is :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Failed to resize 0-th input: Attempting to resize a fixed-size tensor.
```

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to android go through this free course on tensorflow-lite

https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-tensorflow-lite--ud190

This will give you a intro on deployment on android

In the android code, can you try sending float instead of float[]

Comment: i tried sending float instead of float[] but it does not works for me....